# Number to Human Size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently using Rails 4 and i was wondering if there was any way to make

```
= number_to_human_size(plan.storage, delimiter: ',')
```

always output in Gigabytes. So even tho the number of bytes it is reading really equals 1 TB it will display 1,024 GB instead.

Thanks

Comment: That defeats the purpose of `number_to_human_size`. If you need GB always, why not just divide by 2^30?

Comment: what exactly are you asking for? you WANT GB, or it GIVES GB? if you want GB, you could `1.terabyte / 1.gigabyte` if it GIVES GB, that's wrong `ApplicationController.helpers.number_to_human_size(1024.gigabyte, precision: 1) # "1 TB"`